# Shorter way to change content when radio button is clicked

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I wonder if there's a shorter way of doing that:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {           
        $("#deliverer").change(function() {
         $("#opttuser").hide();
         $("#optdeliverer").show();
        });
        $("#tuser").change(function() {
         $("#optdeliverer").hide();
         $("#opttuser").show();
       });
     });
    </script>
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" value="deliverer" name="type"/>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="tuser" id="tuser" />
    <div id='optuser'>//some input fields</div>
    <div id='optdeliverer'>//some other input fields
```

It works without any problem but I have the feeling that this can be done in a much shorter way.So is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this... I added `checked` and hid the opposite div using css ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/XFKLC/)):

html

```
<input type="radio" id="deliverer" value="deliverer" name="type" checked />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="tuser" id="tuser" />
<div id='optuser'>//some input fields</div>
<div id='optdeliverer'>//some other input fields</div>
```

code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deliverer, #tuser").change(function() {
        $("#optdeliverer, #optuser").toggle();
    });
});
```

css

```
#optdeliverer { display: none; }
```